# Run some code just before disconnect event in Puppetter

Tags: puppeteer

I have gone through the Puppeteer [api](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md) and there doesn't seem to be any event that fires just before the browser closes. I need to run some code just before the browser is closed. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: it is true that it can not be achieved via the puppeteer API. calling your desired code just before `await browser.close()` isn't an option?

Comment: No, I dont programmatically close the browser, the user closes the browser

Comment: For now I have come up with a very hacky solution to my actual problem, but an event that fires just before the browser "disconnects" would be wonderful